# Spartacus add to cart

Tags: angular, spartacus-storefront

With Spartacus I have been able to change the PDP call to take an extra parameter which is the store code and its working fine. But when I add the product to the cart the api call fails because the store code is not being passed through.

I have started by extending the active-cart and multi-cart services to take my extra parameter and I am struggling with one of the private variables that are used in the function that are not exposed.

Am I on the right path or is there an easier way to add a parameter to this call? Is an intercepter going to work?

Comment: Hi Ross, I am stuck at exactly same juncture. Would love to know how you were able to solve this issue? Thank you.

Comment: @RajPawanGumdal look at the accepted answer.

Comment: I tried the way mentioned in the answer, OccCartEntryAdapter is not injectable with root (providedIn: 'root'). So I am not able to replace the OccCartEntryAdapter with my custom adapter class not matter what I try. I wonder how you were able to replace it with your custom class.

Comment: Sorry its been ages since I did this so you would need to just use what I used at the time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the easy way for you, if you are using **Spartacus 4.1.x**

1 - Create a service that will provide the store code (maybe you already have it)

2 - Override original configuration for Occ addEntries endpoint to use your additional parameter (e.g., `addEntries: 'users/${userId}/carts/${cartId}/entries?storeCode=${storeCode}'` )

3 - Extend `OccCartEntryAdapter` from Spartacus, inject the service from Step 1 in the constructor, and override `add` method; the method body will be almost equal as the original Spartacus code, with the additional that you will get the `storeCode` from the service injected, and you will add it to `buildUrl` call:

```
this.occEndpointsService.buildUrl('addEntries', {
  urlParams: { userId, cartId, storeCode: STORE_CODE },
});
```

Please notice that there would be a slight difference if you defined the value to be send inside the body. It won't be on `urlParams`, but in the body (variable `toAdd`), just like it's explained below:

1 - Create a service that will provide the store code (maybe you already have it)

2 - Extend `OccCartEntryAdapter` from Spartacus, inject the service from Step 1 in the constructor, and override `add` method; the method body will be almost equal as the original Spartacus code, with the additional that you will get the `storeCode` from the service injected, and you will add it to the body:

```
const toAdd = {
  quantity,
  product: { code: productCode },
  storeCode: STORE_CODE
};
```

**UPDATED**: If you are using Spartacus 2.1.x, make it with URL query parameters:

1 - Create a service that will provide the store code (maybe you already have it)

2 - Extend `OccCartEntryAdapter` from **Spartacus 2.1.8**, inject the service from Step 1 in the constructor, and override `add` method; the method body will be almost equal as the original Spartacus code, with the additional that you will get the `storeCode` from the service injected, and you will add it to `getUrl` call:

```
this.occEndpointsService.getUrl('addEntries', {
  'addEntries',
  {
    userId,
    cartId,
  },
  { code: productCode, qty: quantity, storeCode: STORE_CODE }
);
```

Please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: storeCode: ${storeCode} it doesnt populate the value even if I swap it from url to body

Comment: @RossRawlins , I've edited the post to literally include description how to do it passing the parameter through the body. Please let me know